# Amazon AWS static page showing URL as Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, web-hosting

I have a domain address with NameCheap. I followed all of the documentation for setting up a hosted zone with Route 53 for my AWS account. I deployed my website and checked to see if it worked using the endpoint URL. It worked fine. After that, I took the 4 NS urls from the Hosted Zone and mapped them in NameCheap following a tutorial I found online. I chose a Custom DNS for the Name Server and placed the 4 NS urls.

This all worked fine, when I go to my domain: www.example.com it shows my website. However it changes the URL to http://example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Is there a way to get it to say www.example.com and not the Amazon endpoint?

It appears that this only happens when I go to www.example.com. When I go to example.com, the url stays as example.com and doesn't change to the end point like it does for www.example.com.

Is there a step I missed?

I have 2 buckets: example.com and www.example.com. www.example.com bucket redirects to example.com as described in the AWS tutorial.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-hosting-your-website.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another s3 bucket named www.example.com, and configure it to redirect to example.com.

Comment: Already have the bucket made and it redirects correctly. Just changes the name.

Comment: I think you have both DNS records pointing to the "example.com" bucket. You need to make sure each DNS record points to the correct bucket.

Comment: I fololwed a new tutorial on the website which is slightly different than the original tutorial on the AWS site. I changed the redirect for the www.example.com bucket to redirect to example.com which is my root bucket. It used to redirect to (http://example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/). Now when I go to www.example.com the url is changed to example.com in the browser. In Route 53 I have my two records sets for www.example.com and example.com. Both point to their respective buckets. Still not sure why when I go to www.example.com it changes to example.com

Comment: *Still not sure why when I go to www.example.com it changes to example.com.* One of the sites is **supposed** to redirect to the other.  Your content should only actually be accessible from one hostname, not both -- search engines do not like it when identical content is directly accessible at more than one hostname, and the conventional wisdom is that this hurts your search rankings ("dilutes your link juice").  The other should redirect to the canonical site, which can be either example.com or www.example.com, whichever you prefer, and that's the bucket where your content goes.

Comment: @MarkB on your comment, it doesn't break the way you might expect if you get the DNS wrong.  Alias records can't point to the wrong endpoint, by design -- Route 53 won't let you create a nonsense Alias, and CNAMEs will usually result in unexpectedly correct behavior for S3 targets that are configured with the wrong target hostname, as long as the S3 region of the wrong target matches the S3 region of the right target, and the endpoint type (website/REST) is right.  Only the `Host:` header matters when S3 tries to identify the intended bucket, and that's unaffected by the intermediate CNAMEs.